# check if json string =1 display one or 2 display two ect

Tags: android, json, string, if-statement

My json array responce for item location as "id_location" : "1" or 2 ect i want to display the equal value " location name" in my site insted of the numbers. So how to check and change it beforre setText , changing it by using ready value from string.xml is a good idea but how to do it 
Thanks in advance

EDIT
This is how i get json

```
  List adlist = new List();

 ad.setTitle(obj.getString("id_location"));
```

With list adapter

-------EDIT 2------ 
If alians saw this in futer.. Thanks to mr.vaspalls
This is the fainal working code :

```
//m.getLocation() is your json returned string
switch(m.getLocation()){
 case "1":  textview.setText("New York");
               break;
 case "2": textview.setText("London");
              break;
  .....
 }
```

Comment: give a better example. What value do you want  to show when location is 1, what for 2 etc..

Comment: A word represent location name like newyork if 1 and london if 2 ect..

Comment: you can use a switch or a enum

Comment: Nice pointed me, but how to determin the cases and where to use it. In listadapter or activity or even json before return value?

Comment: hmm. It depends on what you want to do. If you want to show them on a listview you can make the cases on the adapter.

Comment: Right, so no need to defin cases? I mean if the location is 1 that mean the case is 1 by default or plz give me example to acsept it also. Lets say i get the json value and set it to text now how to use enum with that text string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to do that with `switch` like this

```
switch(id_location){
     case "1":  city = "New York";
                   break;
     case "2": city = "London";
                    break;
      .....
 }
```

Comment: What is id_location stand for

Comment: switch(obj.getString("id_location")

Comment: Or switch(string) where string is a value of textview getText().toString()?

Comment: If the value is the index of the city yes

Answer (score 1):

if you already know all the default values for the cities, you can either save them in the String.xml for save it in a class like this

```
String[] location = {"","London","Berlin","Mascow"}
```

> OR

```
 String[] location = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.location);
```

I made the first index empty as i don't know if you will be getting a location value for it.

> but if you have a value for 0 like "some city", then location array should not be empty at index 0

```
int index = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("id_location"));
textView.setText(""+location[i]);
```

Comment: Also notice my json return string not int

Comment: I didnt understand why u make it empty please explain more

Comment: ok, i have updated the answer, now you can read JSON String, convert that to a number

Comment: No  int  in my json array

Comment: @H4F, your json array does not need to have an int, you get the string value of **id_location** convert that to an int value so you can find the index of array where the relevant city location name

Comment: Swich much easyer and flexable thanks any way iwill try both